# How to properly use a function integrate in R?

Tags: r

Here is the raw data:

```
x
         V1      V2
1  15260.14 0.04629
2  15260.16 0.22787
3  15260.17 0.68676
4  15260.19 0.89477
5  15260.20 0.50650
6  15260.22 0.13612
7  15260.23 0.07962
8  15260.25 0.14235
9  15260.26 0.43131
10 15260.28 0.73034
11 15260.29 0.55780
12 15260.31 0.19124
13 15260.32 0.06062
```

Here is the Gaussian mixture I'd like to integrate.
[image]

I use a function `normalmixEM` from package `mixtools` in R in order to get parameters lambda (probability that random point will be from distribution d1,d2), mu (mean intensity of peak1, peak2), sigma(variance of peak1 and peak2):

```
x2 <- normalmixEM(x$V2)
lambda <- x2$lambda
mu <- x2$mu
sigma <- x2$sigma
```

But the function outputs weird results:

```
     lambda        mu      sigma
[1,] 0.5322349 0.1253665 0.06261427
[2,] 0.4677651 0.6288776 0.16119104
```

The first row corresponds to the first peak and the second to the second peak accordingly. It is clear from the plot above, that for the first peak the mean is not 0.12, the mean mu should be higher for the first peak, instead it is very small, also the sigma for the second peak 0.16 is not possible, 0.16 is more like two variances.

Then I create a function that computes the probabilities:

```
Gaussianmix <- function(lambda, mu, sigma, x) {
  lambda*1/(sigma * sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-1/2 * (x-mu)/sigma)}
Gaussianmix <- Vectorize(FUN = Gaussianmix, vectorize.args = c("lambda", "mu", "sigma"))
```

The function outputs zeros:

```
Gaussianmix(lambda,mu,sigma = sigma, x=seq(15260.14,15260.32,by=0.005))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    0
 [2,]    0    0
 [3,]    0    0
 [4,]    0    0
 [5,]    0    0
```

I cannot find the error in the function Gaussianmix.

Then when I try to integrate, the function outputs another error:

```
integrate(f=Gaussianmix(lambda = lambda, mu = mu, sigma = sigma)), 
          lower = 15260.14, upper = 15260.32)
    argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

If I enter the value of argument x, then the error message is that function Gaussianmix is not a function (because all arguments have been entered), so I don't know where should I put the x argument.

I tried the function trapz() that approximates the area by summing up the values at given points x:

```
trapz(x$V1, x$V2)
[1] 0.06987896
```

But the result is again too small to be the area of V1XV2.

Comment: I don't see what your plot has to do with the code you show.  The code never uses `x$V1`.

Comment: Try `caTools::trapz(x$V1, x$V2)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I edited the post and added the result of trapz(x$V1, x$V2). The value is way too small to be the area of mixed gaussian model.

Comment: No, I don't believe it is. The x axis range is small, with a difference between min and max of 0.15 only and max(y) == 0.8. And `0.15*0.8 == 0.12`.

Comment: Why are you inputting `V2` (the density) to `mixtools` when `V1` are your observations?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of things, here is how to setup this problem with the given parameters for GM.

```r
# For plotting
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2

# Function to integrate
gm <- function(x, lambda, mu, sigma){
  lambda[1]*dnorm(x, mu[1], sigma[1]) + lambda[2]*dnorm(x, mu[2], sigma[2])
}

# Parameters
lambda <- c(.53, 1 - .53)
mu <- c(.13, .63)
sigma <- c(.06, .16)

# Plot the density
ggplot() +
  xlim(-.25, 1.25) +
  stat_function(fun = ~gm(.x, lambda, mu, sigma), n = 10^6)
```

[image]

```r
# Integrate part of the distribution
integrate(
  gm, 0, 1, lambda, mu, sigma
)
#> 0.9870854 with absolute error < 1e-04
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>